# asp.net c# need to redirect to another page with value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page that has a gridview control that lists item info and has options to view the items in detail, and also to open a page to edit the item and save the result as a "clone". This works fine, but now I want to add a button to the detail view page to clone the record without having to return to the list page and select the clone item.

working gridview control on list page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Submitted     Questions" AllowSorting="True"
CaptionAlign="Left" EmptyDataText="You have not submitted any Questions." PageSize="5" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#cccccc">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submitted Date" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Submit/Detail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Clone" runat="server" Text="Create Clone" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Clone.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Current attempt at the button control:

dropped the javascript below and moved to code behind:

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="CloneButton" runat="server" Text="Clone This Question" OnClick="CloneButton_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void CloneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Submit/Clone.aspx?Id=" + txt_QuestionID);
    }
```

Now it looks like the app is trying to open the clone page but is having issue with interpreting the value passed for Id?

Error occuring here on the clone page: Error received is "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
using (Conn)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_CloneSElect", Conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));
            command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Ignore below here as no longer used (saved for reference to notes already submitted).

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(QuestionID) { location.href = '~/Submit/Clone.aspx?Id=' + QuestionID; }
 </script>
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="CloneButton" runat="server" OnClientClick='redirect(<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>; return false' Text="Clone Question" />
```

Button is not inside of a table, grid, or other control set.

Comment: How specifically does this not work as you expect?  Where does it fail?  Redirecting with an identifier for the record is certainly what I'd do.  Then on the `Clone.aspx` page you'd use that identifier from the query string to get the record and "clone" it.

Comment: It will work if you put button in the grid.

Comment: @j.v. there is no grid on the detail page that I want to put the button on. The gridview control from the list page is shown only to show a working control that needs to be duplicated to another page and control type (hope that makes sense).

Comment: You cannot use `<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>` outside a GridView (or Repeater, ListView etc). And if the button is on the details page, then don't you have the ID already?

Comment: @VDWWD Ok, if I can't use the EVAL on the submit page, what can I use? How do I feed the ID to the redirect properly so that it works? This is my first ASP.NET application, so very new to this.

Comment: So far you have talked about a `list page`, `details page`, `another page`, `edit page` and a `clone page`. It's not very clear as to where you have an ID and where you want one. As derloopkat answered you can send ID's around using QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues.

```
OnClientClick='redirect(<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>; return false'
```

has a parentheses missing after >

```
OnClientClick='redirect(<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>); return false'
```

Also

```
location.href = '~/Submit/Clone.aspx?Id=' + QuestionID;
```

is inside an ordinary html script tag so ~ won't be replaced by server

If <%#Eval("QuestionID") %> returns a string like QUEST3123234 you'd need to add quotation marks. If it's a number, then they are not needed.

Comment: I tried changing the ~ to the local environment of 'localhost:53269' but still get the same result, the current detail record is reloaded.

Comment: what is your code behind for creating a clone record?

Comment: I changed the button to use code behind with response.redirect (see edit in original question, now the app tries to open the clone page but is having issues with the past value (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="CloneButton" runat="server" Text="Clone This Question" OnClick="CloneButton_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void CloneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Submit/Clone.aspx?Id=" + txt_QuestionID.Text);
    }
```

Thanks to all for assisting to jar a newbies brain cells.